# Printing a pointer in C

Tags: c

I'm playing around with pointers in C, trying to figure things out.

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

   int *p, i[5], value;
   i[0]=6;
   i[1] = 10;
   p=&i[0];

   (*p)++;
   printf("%d\n", i[0]); /* should print 7. */

   *p++;
   value = *p;
   printf("%d\n", value);

   return 0;

 }
```

Why do I need to put the expression, value = *p? Whenever, I try and print ("%d", p), it gives me an error. Why is that? thanks.

Comment: Hmm I wonder what error it gives you...

Comment: just tested your code with llvm, it's working for me, I indeed get `7`, `10`. For which I fixed the missing comma, obviously.

Comment: Works fine for me too (after adding the semicolon after `p=&i[0]`).

Comment: Btw what do you think `*p++` should do? :)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo and my question rather was why can't I just write "%d", p. Why does the asterisk need to be there.

Comment: use `"%p"` for pointer.

Comment: It just shifts the pointer to a different position in the array????

Comment: Because `%d` specifies an *int* and `p` is a pointer, not an int. You should use `%p` if you want to print the pointer `p`.

Comment: `p++` increments the pointer yes. But why is there a `*` before `p++`? It's not doing anything useful.

Comment: *(p++) and (*p)++ are not the same things, the first increments the value of p, the memory address stored in the variable labeled p, whereas the second accesses the memory at the address contained by the variable labeled p and increments that value. Please read the [C Language by Kernighan & Ritchie](http://www.iups.org/media/meeting_minutes/C.pdf)!

Comment: Why does it increment the pointer to the next array value, and subsequently increase the address by 4?????

Comment: `p` is of type `int*`. To print an `int*` value, convert it to `void*` and used `%p`: `printf("p = %p\n", (void*)p);`

Comment: p++ increments the pointer p to point "one int higher" in memory (because p is an int*).  An int has sizeof(int) == 4 on your machine, therefore the increment increases the p's value by 4.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I need to put the expression, `value = *p`?

You don't need to do that. You could do:

```
printf("%d\n", *p);
```

which is strictly the same.

> why can't I just write "%d", p. Why does the asterisk need to be there?

Because the following:

```
printf("%d\n", p);
```

wouldn't have the same meaning, `p` contains the address of the value you point to which would be what you'd printout there: that's the A-B-Cs of pointers.

Please refer to a [good handbook](http://www.iups.org/media/meeting_minutes/C.pdf) for learning more about it, because I could teach you about pointers for hours, but all the course material is already out there, and that's from that book that I've learned it myself! ;-)

> it gives me an error. Why is that?

Otherwise your code works fine, apart from the missing semicolon on this line:

```
p=&i[0]
```

Comment: Why isn't printf("%d\n", p); the same thing?

Comment: @MatthewS , arguments don't match. `%d` expects an `int` whereas you supply `p` which is an argument of type `int*`.

Comment: Of course it does not which is why I said "something like". My point is for the OP to learn pointers correctly using resources, not through a short SO answer.